# Use dynamic programming to solve the minimum absolute difference between two sub-arrays

Tags: algorithm, dynamic

Split A into 2 sub-arrays A1 and A2. A=(a1,a2....an). 
To make |A1|+|A2| minimum (condition is that a1 belongs to A1, a2 belongs to A2). 
|{3,4,5}| = |3-4|+|4-5| = 2 
How to use dynamic programming to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: I didn't really understand what you are asking. Shouldn't you consider also |3-5|? Can you make a more accurate example of the two input arrays, and the output desired?

Comment: What's the definition of `|A|` here?